# OutOfMemoryException with EntitySet (local db) object in PhoneApplicationService.Current.State upon OnActivate

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am getting an OutOfMemoryException when resuming from dormant state when an object that has EntitySet in it is saved in Application State. Here is an example code.

```
var list = new TaskList() { Title = "AA" };
list.TaskItems = new EntitySet<TaskItem>();
list.TaskItems.Add(new TaskItem() { Notes = "BB" });            
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["CurrentList"] = list;//Fails only when resuming
var list1 = (TaskList)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["CurrentList"]; // WORKS FINE
//PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["CurrentList"] = "AnyString" //Works fine;
```

Now I press "Start" and navigate away from the application. Then I press "Back" button causing it to resume from Dormant state, it says "Resuming" for a while and I get an OutOfMemory exception after some time.

When I store and retrieve the object from "State", it works fine. It's throwing an exception only when "Resuming". Does anyone know why? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question. I had Circular reference between the TaskList and TaskItem object which failed during de-serialization. I was thinking it failed due to EntitySet and asked this question. Sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

In code you show that you are saving `CurrentList` to application state when you application is resuming from Dormant state. I think you should save to application state when you are tombstoning, not resuming.

> Dormant
>
> When the user navigates forward, away from an application, after the
>   Deactivated event is raised, the operating system will attempt to put
>   the application into a dormant state. In this state, all of the
>   application’s threads are stopped and no processing takes place, but
>   the application remains intact in memory. If the application is
>   reactivated from this state, the application does not need to
>   re-create any state, because it has been preserved.
>
> If new applications are launched after an application has been made
>   dormant, and these applications requires more memory than is available
>   to provide a good user experience, the operating system will begin to
>   tombstone dormant applications to free up memory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008(v=vs.92).aspx